# How to store image in json file using local path?

Tags: json, reactjs

I want to locally store image path in a `json` file.
This is for a `json` storing data image path:

```
[ { "image": "./Component/Images/image file } ]
```

React:

```
[ { "image": "./Component/Images/image file } ] // React render(){ image tag and source={this.props.image}/> }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? It is quite unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Thank for the reply Tien Duong. I want my json data value "./Component/Images/picture.jpg to link to my root folder named Image.

Comment: When I do 
"image": "h t t p://placekitten.com/100/200" // This is just fine to display the image
But when i have a image folder in my root folder, I do this
"image": "./Component/Images/picture.jpg //This does not work for me